# Evaluating a specific definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Can someone help me evaluate the following integral?

$$\frac{1}π\int_{-π}^π x^{2n}cos(\frac{nπx}L) dx$$

Integration by parts does not seem to work.
$$\frac{1}π\int_{-π}^π x^{2n}cos(\frac{nπx}L) dx = \frac{1}π([x^{2n}sin(\frac{nπx}L)\frac{L}{nπ}]_{-π}^π-\frac{2L}π\int_{-π}^πx^{2n-1}sin(\frac{nπx}L)dx)$$ 
If I continue to integrate by parts, then I won't arrive at an answer as I will keep getting powers of x.

Comment: What do you obtain with integration by parts? Could you edit your answer (using the "edit" button) so as to show us your attempt?

Comment: can you tell us something about the variables?

Comment: Forgot to do so sorry, n and L are just constants and n is a positive integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Fourier series integral, in which case $L = \pi$ which would simplify the calculations a bit.  But in any case, if you integrate by parts twice, the new integrand should be a constant times $x^{2(n-1)}\cos(n\pi x/L)$.  This gives you a "reduction" formula.  Applying the reduction formula repeatedly should give you a nice pattern.  (Especially of $L=\pi$.)

Comment: Indeed it is, I will try and see what I get, thanks :)